# WooCommerce product url append custom string in slug

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I have WooCommerce store and I need to append custom variable string in single product urls for SEO. We have custom select option in single product page and I want to append that value in product url once user select that option.

Page should be reloaded so I can set meta according to as well.

Current URL: https://my-sample-site.com/product/iphone/

Now on that single product page I have option to choose model. So for ex. when someone selects 14, new URL should be

https://my-sample-site.com/product/iphone/14/

and user should be stay on same product page after reloaded.

Is there any way to achive this using rewrite or something? I do not want to add rewrite rule in a way that redirects user to another page. It must stay on same single product page with change in URL.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired functionality of appending a custom variable string to the product URL in WooCommerce, you can use JavaScript to manipulate the URL on the client side without actually reloading the entire page. Here's a high-level overview of the steps you can follow:

**1. Modify the Product URLs:**
In your WooCommerce setup, ensure that you have custom select options available for each product. You can use product attributes or custom fields for this purpose.

**2. Add JavaScript to Manipulate URLs:**
Add the following JavaScript code to your WordPress theme. This code will update the URL when the user selects an option, without triggering a full page reload. It uses the HTML5 History API to modify the URL.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Get the current product URL
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    
    // Attach event listener to the select option
    $('.single-product select').on('change', function() {
        var selectedOption = $(this).val();
        var newURL = currentURL + selectedOption + '/';
        
        // Update the URL without triggering a full page reload
        history.pushState({}, '', newURL);
    });
});
```

This code snippet listens for changes in the select option, appends the selected value to the current URL, and updates the URL using the History API.

**3. Handling URL Changes on the Server:**
Since you want to update meta according to the appended string and ensure the content matches the selected model, you need to handle this on the server-side. You can use a combination of JavaScript and PHP to do this.

You'll need to hook into WordPress actions and filters to detect the updated URL and modify the content accordingly. Here's a simplified example of how you might approach this:

```
function update_product_meta_based_on_url() {
    global $post;
    
    // Get the current URL
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));
    
    // Extract the appended string from the URL
    $appended_string = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $current_url);
    
    // Use the $appended_string to update the meta or modify the content
    // You can update the post meta, modify the content, or perform any other desired action
}
add_action('wp', 'update_product_meta_based_on_url');
```

Note that this is a simplified example and might need further customization based on your exact needs and the structure of your WooCommerce setup.

Remember to test thoroughly after implementing these changes to ensure that the behavior aligns with your requirements and that it's providing the desired SEO benefit without causing unexpected issues.

Comment: I want to have this url land me on same single product page as well https://my-sample-site.com/product/iphone/14/ because it is possible that some user may share that url to other users so it should work as well. Not just change of url for current user